# Using Google Docs to work with Europass CV

Tags: google-docs, file-conversion

Is there any trick to make **Google Docs** get the correct layout of a [**Europass CV**](http://europass.cedefop.europa.eu/en/documents/curriculum-vitae/templates-instructions)?

I keep trying and trying but I cant get that to work well, all my tried go into something like this:

[image]

and then:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The current version of Google Docs is doing a good job for converting the Europass CV .doc templates to the Google Docs format.

[image: Europass CV converted to Google Doc]

Comment: yes, but my question was made in 2011 :) anyway, thanks :)